# Angular duplicate for milliseconds before render completely

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I render my template this duplicate for milliseconds until compile cycle finish. Someone know how can solve it?

Using Angular Batarang I could see a lot of watchers (5k) and a large digest cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `ngCloak` directive.  From the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

> The `ngCloak` directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.